# Need an idea on what to check next for random computer... freeze?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, ssd, freeze

I have an odd problem with the computer that I built this year randomly, freezing I suppose would be the best word..  You can see the important system specs [here](http://www.3dmark.com/3dm/2937094).

Now, the reason that I don't want to specifically call it freezing, is that it doesn't come to a complete stop, at least not in the normal sense.  I can be using the computer perfectly fine, and then actions that I engage in programs/Windows all of a sudden never happen, even though the mouse is still moving..

As an example, earlier, I turned on my computer, logged into windows, and then opened Explorer.  When I went to open up C:\ I double clicked on the C-Drive, and then the mouse just turned into the waiting circle.  I can MOVE the window around, but attempting to adjust its visibility (minimize/close/resize) does nothing.  I can open up the Start Screen and begin to type something, but the start screen just stays open, nothing else happens at this point.  CTRL+ALT+DEL fails to bring anything up.

These errors happen not just with explorer though.  I can be merrily (getting to that time of year) using VS2013, uTorrent, Plex Home Theater, Chrome, etc - and things all of a sudden stop responding (as in to mouse clicks/actions), yet windows doesn't recognize them as Not Responding (most of the time at least).  After this starts to happen, I have to restart, no matter what.

Now the first thought that goes through your head with that example is either malware/virus/etc, or corrupt Windows.  However, this is a problem I've faced on the initial boot into windows after a reformat **without** having been on the internet.  I've faced this problem intermittently, sometimes going over a month without having an issue, but every once in a while, it acts up again like crazy - this is one of those weeks.  I'd love for it to actually be a BSOD issue, because at least then I could use windbg and find out what was wrong, but I don't get memory dumps for these since I am the one forcing it to restart since it stops listening.

I am leaning towards this being an issue with my SSD, like the SSD is losing connection or something.  In my head that makes sense, since I know Window's caches and runs a lot of the experience out of memory, I wouldn't expect an HDD problem to bring the system to a BSOD, which DOESN'T happen.

Now, I promise, I am not a computer NOOB..  Here is just some of the things that I have done to diagnose this issue:

1. One of the first things I checked after building the computer, and after having these issues, was running MemTest.  Let run for +24 hours, no issues from either stick.  Last I checked too, my mem was on the QVL
2. Corrupt installation of Windows - as mentioned, I've reformatted..  At least 5 times now (not just because of the issue, I just REALLY like that new computer scent..  uh, responsiveness.
3. Power - Since I think this might be an issue with the actual drive, I considered that it might be an issue with the drive getting enough juice.  I just switched the drive onto a new SATA controller on the MOBO, and hooked it up into a new modular cable on my PSU (1300W EVGA) - just in case.  However, I have already had the issue again since getting back up.
4. SSD SMART returns no issues (currently that is).  That is after short and extended tests.
5. Malware/ETC - should've been eliminated w/Windows reformat..  But, in the off chance it wasn't, or the MOBO/SSD came from Amazon with a rootkit preinstalled, I've run numerous malwarebytes/spybot/etc in a PE off a USB to verify.
6. Drivers - installed all drivers after issues originally, still didn't resolve issues
7. Windows Event Logs - Can't see anything in the event logs at all, just the system running perfectly fine, and then a log saying 'The previous shutdown was unexpected blah blah blah'
8. Bribing - didn't work.
9. Other various things that I can't think of currently.

As mentioned above, at this point, I think the issue may be the SSD, so my next plan of action may be to image the SSD to a partition of one of my HDD's and run from there for a time being to see if that STILL has an issue.

If you have any ideas as to what the issue may be, I'd be happy to hear them.  As mentioned above, there are several things that I've tried, that I can't even think of right now, but if you ask/tell me, I can post the information regarding that up here.  Like I said, with the actions that seem to be happening with Windows not completely hardstopping, just not listening any more, I think it may be the SSD, but I'm up for suggestions.

Comment: If you think it might be your disk then **backup important data** now. The disk could just fail completely without further warning.

Comment: As I said above ,I'm not a noob when it comes to computers. .. Computers 101: Always backup.  My plan above is simply a full bit by bit backup, so that I don't necessarily have to reformat, and can compare stability between ssd, and new partition on an hdd without anything else changing.

Comment: Can the person that down voted at least post why???? Details left out, unclear, not pertinent to SU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a disk was failing, I got these large system wide pauses at random intervals.  Nothing in my logs indicated this was happening.  Ended up finding out when the disk finally died.  Once the disk was replaced all of these type of problems disappeared without doing anything else.  This might be what is happening to you.

Comment: Same happened when my disk started to die, so glad I figured it out beforehand and got an SSD!

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this since no one else provided any actual answer.  I do believe it is the disk, or the disk controller on the MOBO.  Going to work on it this weekend.  Thanks for answering!